# How do you trigger fullscreen with mediaelement.js?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'd like to trigger full screen when a MediaElement video is played.

```
$('video').on("play", function () {
     //fullscreen mode
});
```

Any ideas?  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have jquery version 1.7 or later to use the on function.  Then this should work:

```
player = new MediaElementPlayer('video');
$('video').on("play", function() {
    player.enterFullScreen();
});
```